# Pass javascript array to a canvasjs (diagram) script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, canvasjs

I have the following script and want to pass the array "arr" to another script (use in a canvasjs diagram).

How do I use it easiest? OBS! Hope the deleted code isn't imported couldn't post so much code.

```
  var arr = [];
  for (let set of vecka) {
  };
  for (let set of sets) {
    arr.push({'datum': set.time, 'procent': procent});
  }
  x += "</table>";
```

Comment: what do you mean by passing the array to another script. How and where you currently call it ?

Comment: Can you create [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/) with your code, which community can checkout & help you?